# Webpack Compilation Error with Cypress 10 and Cucumber in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have seen other similar questions in this site, but non of them have a satisfatory solution for me. I don't have any webpack.config.js file since we take the default configuration from angular. Please, see below the corresponding image to have a better sight of my problem.

[image]

Other configurations in my project:

package.json

```js
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
"nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
"json": {
  "enabled": true
},
"stepDefinitions": "**/cypress/e2e/**/*.js",
"step_definitions": "**/cypress/e2e/**/*.js"
},
```

cypress.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
export default defineConfig({
e2e: {
// We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
// You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
},
specPattern: '**/e2e/**/*.feature',
"supportFile": false,
chromeWebSecurity: false
},
})
```

**Update 1:**
Hello @Wirtuald, thanks for responding me.
I began getting this issue on a quite complex angular project. So, I created a basic project from scratch and ***I still have the same issue***. Then, I give you below all the information of this new project:

- I dont have "plugins" folder
- versions on package.json:

  ```js
    "devDependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.2.0",
    "cypress": "^10.2.0"
    },
  ```
- preprocessor config on package.json

  ```js
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
  "json": {
  "enabled": true
  },
  "stepDefinitions": [
  "[filepath].{js,ts}",
  "cypress/e2e/**/*.{js,ts}"
  ]
  ```

  }
- cypress.config.js:

  ```js
    const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
    module.exports = defineConfig({
    e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    // implement node event listeners here
    },
   },
  });
  ```

-project structure

[image]

- direct-attention-steps.js

```js
    import { Given, When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
    Given("Access to NXSuite", () => {
    cy.visit("https://www.nxsuite.com");
    })
```

Comment: Finally I have been able to solve this issue by follwing the steps on here: https://testersdock.com/cypress-10-upgrade/
Hope it will helpful to those who are facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

You're just missing the webpack process, [from quick-start](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md)

> Then configure your preferred bundler to process features files. See examples/ for how-to using Browserify, Esbuild or Webpack.

The webpack.ts example is given here [cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/examples/webpack-ts/cypress.config.ts](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/examples/webpack-ts/cypress.config.ts).

It needs additional installs for `@cypress/webpack-preprocessor` and `ts-loader`.

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import * as webpack from "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

async function setupNodeEvents(
  on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
  config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
  await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.ts$/,
              exclude: [/node_modules/],
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "ts-loader",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              test: /\.feature$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/webpack",
                  options: config,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    })
  );

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    supportFile: false,
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```

---

In **Update1** in `cypress.config.js` you have a typo

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
```

should be

```js
export default defineConfig({
```

Comment: I tried to follow the examples using the recommended one, I mean: "esbuild" but I still have the issue:

"Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/e2e/nxsuite/client-attention/direct-attention.feature 1:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders"

I will try nex with webpack, but not sure what i am doing wrong. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to install @cypress/webpack-preprocessor

Comment: Thanks Andy, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an issue with the latest version of `cypress`

I'm using

```
"@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^11.2.0",
"cypress": "^10.2.0",
```

First, make sure that you use the latest version of `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` which fix some compatibilty issues with cypress 10. See https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/722# for futher info.

Also, latest version of cypress has removed plugin file. In my case, migrating all the code from `cypress/plugins/index.js` inside `setupNodeEvents` method solved the issue. See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/migration-guide#Plugins-File-Removed

The devil is in the details, it could also be related to your plugin file itself. Maybe you could share it, so that we can help you better. Can you also share what version of "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor" you use

Hope it will help you,

Comment: Hello @Wirtuald, thanks for responding me, I appreciate that. Please, take a look into the "Update 1" that I put in the main question :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above solution:

```
import webpack from "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor";
```

and I removed the rule for .ts files, keeping just the .feature rule in the webpack config.

It all worked ok after that

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar problem. Besides tweaking scripts my workaround was to downgrade Node from 18 to 16.13.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).