# Cypress mysql connector throws an error Error: Webpack Compilation Error

Tags: mysql, cypress, mysql-connector, cypress-component-test-runner

I am new to cypress. My cypress test suite are runing good before configure a mysql connector to connect to mysql database. It throw below  `Webpack Compilation Error` error when add mysql connector code in `plugins >> Index.js`. following BDD apporche so feature file is used.

**Error encountered:**

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/integration/Login.feature 1:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> Feature: Login test
```

**Code in plugins >> index.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2')
function queryTestDb(query, config) {  
  // creates a new mysql connection using credentials from cypress.json env's
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(Cypress.env('passwrd'))
  // start connection to db
  connection.connect()
  // exec query + disconnect to db as a Promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
      if (error) reject(error)
      else {
        connection.end()
        // console.log(results)
        return resolve(results)
      }
    })
  })
};

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  // Usage: cy.task('queryDb', query)
  on('task', {
    queryDb: query => {
      return queryTestDb(query, config)
    },
  })
};
```

**Calling function in step definition**

```
cy.task(
        "queryDb",
        `select * from city LIMIT 5`
      ).then(count => {
        expect(count).to.have.lengthOf(1);
      });
```

**Cypress.json**

```
 "env1": {
        "db":
         {"host": "xxxx.test.mysql", 
          "user": "xxxxxxx",
           "passwrd": "xxxxxxx", 
           "database": "main" , 
           "connectionLimit":10 
          }
        }
```

**tsconfig.js**

```
"compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "outDir": "./built",
      "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
     "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false, 
     "allowJs": true,
      "types": ["cypress", "node", "cypress-xpath"]
     
    }
```

tried lots of ways likes

- by refresh installation of node_modules
- reinstall `mysql2` and  `mysql` package
- reinstalling @cypress/webpack-preprocessor

but nothing works.

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729879/webpack-compilation-error-with-cypress-10-and-cucumber-in-angular

Comment: @user9847788 Thanks for reply, similary error, but it arrises when added mysql connector . Already tried with all the options specified  it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729879/webpack-compilation-error-with-cypress-10-and-cucumber-in-angular  . it is not working for me

Comment: @user9847788 , still i am  looking for solution, Pleas me if you could ..Thanks